# Request with count and group by

Tags: sql, rdbms

| id | id_person | id_equipement | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 250 | [date_1] |
| 2 | 2 | 250 | [date_2] |
| 3 | 3 | 50 | null |
| 4 | 2 | 50 | [date_3] |

I want to get the id of every person for which there is more than 1000 line and the date is null.

I tried with :

```sql
select id_person  
from table 
where date is null
group by id_equipement 
having count(is_equipement) > 1000
```

Comment: Use `SUM()`, not `COUNT()` to sum values!

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you SELECT` (_except those who are arguments to set functions_,)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & don't belong in question posts. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [answer] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as you need the id of persons appearing more than 1000 times

```
select id_person  
from table 
where date is null
group by id_person
having count(id_person) > 1000
```